# Webpart Search Content simple OOTB search for a Timeout 15 seconds

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

OOTB Search Content webpart on a OTTB Publishing site. Intermitantly it timesout.

Farm, 2 WFE 2 APP
Search is running on APP, Query service is on WFE

Sevice Pack SP1 Sharepoint 2013

I know if i move all search components to one server this problem goes away.

Been down the Certificate not being correct....appear to make some improvements

Can oftern reproducing it by leave IE9 open wait 20+mins then press f5, rest of page reloads fine search webpart timesout: 15 seconds message.

Press f5 will probably then work, for a bit.

Nothing in Event log on all servers.

VMware hosts, with net scaler, set to Round robin.

ULS Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry : Exceptions occurred when evaluating the flow.  Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException: Query execution timed out. ---> System.TimeoutException: Query timeout: Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Query.MarsLookupComponent.LookupService.QueryClient.QuerySession, timeout is: 00:00:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. Its a latancy issue. One of the web frontends was in a different data centre. Moved it to the same data centre, and the timeout error was resolved. Search webpart was also instant.

http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/stretched-farms-and-sharepoint-2013/

Is a very good article, plus a neat powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the XSLT transform timeout ?

$myfarm = Get-SPFarm

$myfarm.XsltTransformTimeOut

You may have this set to 1 (second)

Try setting to 5 (or more)

Comment: Content Search Webparts do not use xml, they return results in Json. Plus why change an out of box setting. This should work. Something in the infrastructure is causing this to timeout

Comment: This was a latacy issue on our Data Centre. One of the vms was the other data centre. Ping reponse times must be under <2ms